# Entity Framework Code First Migrations with Interfaces

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to run EF code-first migrations using Attribute/annotations approach with interfaces as property types. We have built an entire base architecture with interfaces and are using these to implement concrete classes and want to enable migrations. EF doesn't seem to be associating the Foreign Key relationships correctly though. Is there any way to correct this?

Here is an example:

I have an IStateProvince interface as follows:

```
 public interface IStateProvince
{

    string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }

    ICountry Country { get; set; }

}
```

I also have an ICountry interface as follows:

```
public interface ICountry
{

    string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(2)]
    string TwoLetterIsoCode { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(3)]
    string ThreeLetterIsoCode { get; set; }

    int NumericIsoCode { get; set; }

    List<IStateProvince> StateProvinces { get; set; }
}
```

I have created concrete Implementations as follows:

```
[Table("TypeData.Country")]
public class Country : BaseSqlEntity, ICountry
{

    [Required, MaxLength(250)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string TwoLetterIsoCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ThreeLetterIsoCode { get; set; }

    public int NumericIsoCode { get; set; }

    public virtual List<IStateProvince> StateProvinces { get; set; }

}
```

The State Province is as follows:

```
[Table("TypeData.StateProvince")]
public class StateProvince : BaseSqlEntity, IStateProvince
{

    [Required, MaxLength(3)]
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(250)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid CountryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
    public virtual ICountry Country { get; set; }

}
```

The BaseSqlEntity you see is as follows:

```
public class BaseSqlEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreatedUtc { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateModifiedUtc { get; set; }

    public BaseSqlEntity()
    {
        DateCreatedUtc = DateModifiedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

}
```

I have added the dbsets in the context as follows:

```
public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
public DbSet<StateProvince> StateProvinces { get; set; }
```

Upon running migration, I get the following:

```
public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "TypeData.Country",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 250),
                    TwoLetterIsoCode = c.String(nullable: false),
                    ThreeLetterIsoCode = c.String(nullable: false),
                    NumericIsoCode = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    DateCreatedUtc = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    DateModifiedUtc = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "TypeData.StateProvince",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Abbreviation = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 3),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 250),
                    CountryId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    DateCreatedUtc = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    DateModifiedUtc = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

    }
```

As you will notice, there are no Foreign Key Relationships getting generated because it cannot somehow correlate the ICountry to its implementation Country.

If I change the type from ICountry to Country and comment the interface, it works just fine and correctly generates the relationships.

Is there a way around this? Any help would be very much appreciated. We have built a ton of reusable architecture using interfaces that we would love to use but it seems like this might be a show-stopper.

Comment: try manually adding the Foreign Key to the code generated by migration after running migration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still use the interfaces.
 
Just need to implement the interface properties in the concrete classes as below.

```cs
[Table("TypeData.Country")]
public class Country : BaseSqlEntity, ICountry
{

    [Required, MaxLength(250)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string TwoLetterIsoCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ThreeLetterIsoCode { get; set; }

    public int NumericIsoCode { get; set; }

    public virtual List<StateProvince> StateProvinces { get; set; }

    List<IStateProvince> ICountry.StateProvinces
    {
        get
        {
            return StateProvinces.ToList<IStateProvince>();
        }

        set
        {
            StateProvinces = value.ToList().ConvertAll(o => (StateProvince)o);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```cs
[Table("TypeData.StateProvince")]
public class StateProvince : BaseSqlEntity, IStateProvince
{

    [Required, MaxLength(3)]
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(250)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid CountryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    ICountry IStateProvince.Country
    {
        get
        {
            return Country;
        }

        set
        {
            Country = (Country)value;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That works. I was really hoping there was a simple way of doing this like [ForeignKey("CountryId"), typeof(Country)] and that would've made things so much easier!